Retrieving compactness with special function
Let $(X,\tau_1)$ and $(Y,\tau_2)$ be topological spaces where $Y$ is compact. Consider a function $f:(X,\tau_1)\rightarrow (Y,\tau_2)$ with the following properties:

$f^{-1}(y)$ is compact in $X$ for every $y\in Y$.
$f(E)$ is closed in $Y$ for every closed subset $E\subset X$.

I'm having trouble showing that $X$ is compact under these conditions, and I don't have many references either. My professor called a a function with property 2 a "closed function" but this doesn't seem to be a common terminology.
Either way, here's what I've tried so far.
If $\{O_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is an open cover of $X$, then $\{f^{-1}(y)\cap O_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is an open cover of $f^{-1}(y)$ for any given $y\in Y$. Property $1$ guarantees that there's an finite subcover. Let $B\subset A$ be finite. I wrote
$$f^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(y)\cap \left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in B}O_\alpha\right).$$
This concludes that $f^{-1}(y)\subset \bigcup_{\alpha\in B}O_\alpha$ and there should be other $y$ that I could choose to cover up the rest of X. It is not clear to me how the compactness of $Y$ or property 2 could be of use.

Closed function (map): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps#Closed_maps

@EricTowers provided a link in the comments section with the insight I was missing.
The two statements are equivalent definitions for closed maps:

$f(E)$ is closed in $Y$ for every closed subset $E\subset X$;
$\{y\in Y; f^{-1}(y)\subset U\}$ is open for every open subset $U\subset X$.

The argument is quite straightforward. Consider an open cover $\{O_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ of $X$. From the equivalence stated above, $\{y\in Y; f^{-1}(y)\subset O_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is an open cover of $Y$, which is compact. Thus, there is a finite $B\subset A$ such that $$Y=\bigcup_{\alpha \in B}\{y\in Y; f^{-1}(y)\subset O_\alpha\};$$
and, finally,
$$f^{-1}(Y)=X=\bigcup_{\alpha \in B}\{O_\alpha\}.$$
Therefore, $X$ is compact.
